# avoid repeatation of group members to be captured

Tags: regex

i have regex characters and words as in regex but i want only single member to be selected from this group `\d(?i)(R|k|M|E|next|prev){1,2}`

valid are  - `8RK, 6ME, 9Rnext`

invalid are - `8MM,0RR, 9nextnext`

Please suggest

Comment: Look into negative lookaheads and specify the programming language / tool you're using.

Comment: Is 6MEM valid??

Comment: 6MEM is wrong bacuase we have {1,2} there

Comment: Are you using this regex in Go lang code? If not, try `(?i)(?<![^\W_])\d(?:(R|k|M|E|next|prev)(?!\1)){1,2}(?![^\W_])` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/XxMrQ2/1))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  can you pls explain this and if we add some more groups to this, will it work in the same way  ??

Comment: The `(?<![^\W_])` and `(?![^\W_])` are word boundaries that exclude `_` (`\b` includes `_`). No idea what you mean by adding more groups and where. Your current question is unclear, and I just based my comment on Jan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you might want to use lookarounds, namely a neg. lookahead here:

```
\d(?i)
(?:
    (R|k|M|E|next|prev) # capture group 1
    (?!\1)              # make sure, there's not the same submatch in front
){1,2}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/6UsJCt/1/).

Comment: but adding boundry is problem then (\b|_)\d(?i)(?:(R|k|M|E|next|prev)(?!\1)){1,2}(\b|_)...result has changed..

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work ：)

```
\d\w\w,\s\d\w\w,\s\w.*$
```